# Using a case class apply: No member of type class A in scope for T

Tags: scala, types, implicit, implicit-typing

I am having trouble compiling a function due to implicit conversions. 
I have the following base case classes:

```
sealed abstract class Expr0[T](implicit ev: VectorSpace0[T]) extends ID {...
case class Neg0[T](e: Expr0[T])(implicit ev: VectorSpace0[T]) extends Expr0[T] { ...
```

Then in an object I have the following function

```
  def simplify[T](e: Expr0[T])(implicit ev: VectorSpace0[T]): Expr0[T] = {
    def s(expr: Expr0[T])(implicit ev: VectorSpace0[T]): Result[Boolean, T] = expr match {

      case Neg0(e)                            => 
        val re = s(e)
        val ne = Neg0.apply(re.e)
        if (re.r) new TR(ne) else FR(ne)
```

The code above compiles correctly with no problem. Now I want to create a function that will execute that sequence of statements in the case. So I created the following helper function:

```
  def C[T](f: Expr0[T] => Expr0[T], re: Result[Boolean, T])(implicit ev: VectorSpace0[T]) = {
    val ne = f(re.e); if (re.r) new TR(ne) else FR(ne)
  }
```

And now I try to use so:

```
  def simplify[T](e: Expr0[T])(implicit ev: VectorSpace0[T]): Expr0[T] = {
    def s(expr: Expr0[T])(implicit ev: VectorSpace0[T]): Result[Boolean, T] = expr match {

      case Neg0(e)                            => 
        C(Neg0.apply, s(e))
```

and I get the error:

```
 /src/main/scala/ann/unit/Expr0.scala:412: No member of type class ann.uinit.VectorSpace in scope for T
        C(Neg0.apply, s(e))
               ^
```

I have been poking and prodding this for several hours but no luck. I think the problem here is with the definition of `C[T]` (3rd code snippet). Maybe I have to add something to the definition of the first parameter `f`, which is a function, so that the implicit `T` is correctly determined.

Can anyone advise me on how to correct or further diagnose this problem?

TIA

Comment: Frankly, you have quite a mess there with the nested implicits of the same type and name. The message might be misleading, perhaps the eta expansion in `Neg0.apply` is the culprit, perhaps a missing type inference for `T` in `C[T]`. I suggest you make that call explicit first and see if the error narrows down: `C[T](Neg0[T](_), s(e))`

Comment: Yes, nested implicits of the same type and name are not needed (remnants of refactoring). And you are correct - eta expansion solved it. During my experiments I had the error message suggesting eta but did not click (no explicit T typing required).So.... how do I give the points for the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bit of a mess there with the nested implicits of the same type and name. The message might be misleading, perhaps the **eta expansion in Neg0.apply** is the culprit, perhaps a **missing type inference for T in C[T]**.

I suggest you make that call explicit first and see if the error narrows down:

```
C[T](Neg0[T](_), s(e))
```

Comment: C(Neg0(_), s(e)) works. No need for the type parameter.